# Can a complex function be continuous on a connected complex region (open set + one or more boundary points)

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I have understand that a function of a complex variable can be holomorphic only on a connected open set. “Holomorphicity” of function does not make sense on a closed set or on a non-open region where a few boundary points may be included.

Is there a similar restriction on continuity of a function of complex variables? When it comes to continuity of of functions of real variables, we do have way to define it on closed intervals and open intervals. I haven’t been able to find specific restrictions or allowances when it comes to functions of complex variables.

Examples: say we have $f(z) = 0$ when $\Re(z) > 0$ and $z=0$. Can we say $f(z)$ is continuous on region $\{z=0 \cup \Re(z) >0\}$

Say we have $g(z) = 0$ when $\Re(z) \ge 0$. Can we say $g(z)$ is continuous on closed set $\Re(z) \ge 0$

Comment: Homomorphic has it built in in the definition, kind of artificially, but of course for convenience, of holding on an open set. Note, however, that complex-differentiable doesn't. You can have existence of complex derivative on non-open sets, even more continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity is defined for functions on any subset of $\mathbb{C}$ at all (using the usual $\epsilon$-$\delta$ condition, just restricted to the domain of the function).  Vastly more generally, continuity can be defined for functions between two [topological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space), and any subset of a topological space can be made into a topological space in a natural way.

Comment: By "domain" I just mean the domain of the function, which can be any subset.